# clearing the form element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form  with `id='form_testimonial'`.
Here is my code to clear form element

```
$(':input,:hidden','#form_testimonial')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset')
 .val('');
```

It does clear all value input as well as select option value too, but I don't want to clear values of select option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
$('#form_testimonial input[type="text"]').val('');
```

If you want to include hidden inputs too:

```
$('#form_testimonial').find(input[type="text"],input[type="hidden"]').val('');
```

You can also use:

```
$('#form_testimonial input').filter(function(){
    return this.type == "hidden" || this.type == "text";
}).val('');
```

Comment: `hidden` is also the target.

Answer (score 0):

and `:select` in not selector

```
$(':input,:hidden','#form_testimonial')
.not('select,:button, :submit, :reset')
.val('');
```

instead of selecting all  form element, just select those whose value you want to empty

```
$('#form_testimonial').find('input[type="text"],input[type="hidden"]')
.val('');
```

Comment: I'd think `.not('select, :button, :submit, :reset')` (Note the lack of a `:` on `select`) would work better.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#form_testimonial').find(':input,:hidden').not('select, :button, :submit, :reset').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#form_testimonial')
 .find('input:not([type="button"],[type="submit"],[type="reset"]),textarea')
 .val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form_testimonial input, #form_testimonial textarea')
    .not('select, :button, :submit, :reset').val('');
```